# Debian: How to use "apt-get install" without upgrading dependencies?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies

I already have a package B and want to install a new package A. The installation wants to modify B, but I don't want that to happen.

I need to install the package A.

It has the a dependency on package B and requires to be (>2.0).

I have already installed B in my system with the version 2.1, so my current setup already fulfills the dependency.

But there is a new version (2.2) of the B package in the Debian repository and I don't want it since it conflicts with other stuff.

So, when I install the A package apt also tries to upgrade B.

How can I disable the upgrading of the dependencies or indicate an explicit dependency version without having to edit the packages?

I have read [How do I get apt-get to ignore some dependencies?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies), but it doesn't help me. In the question there, the dependency (B) should not be handled by the repository manager at all. In my case, the repository manager already takes care of the dependency and should continue to do so, just not in this particular action.

Reopen Reviewers: *Please see the comment of [victorgp](https://serverfault.com/users/63136/victorgp) which should have been the answer in the first place.*

Comment: Is not duplicated, so i'm going to anwser myself, use: --no-upgrade

Comment: Try to formulate it more visible, more convincing. Show the easily verifiable, essential differences between the post and the dupe candidate. Only to say, "it is not a dupe", is only rarely enough.

Comment: @peterh I have edited it to be more precise. I had the impression that "The answers there won't help here, and the answers here won't help there" would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

On Debian 8 I've found the option --no-upgrade can help achieving the desired result. For example:

```
apt-get install --no-upgrade php7.0-xmlrpc
```

Comment: This flag will not update php7.0-xmlrpc only. It has no effect on dependency packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `--nodeps` flag with `apt-get` or you can try the debian package utility, `dpkg`, with the option `--ignore-depends`.

Comment: There is no --nodeps flag on apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apt-mark hold package-that-apt-should-leave-alone`.

> hold
>
> hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `--nodeps` flag with `apt-get` or download the package and install it using `dpkg` along with the option `--ignore-depends`