# Using mozjpeg in place of jpeg-turbo including satisfying dependencies

Tags: debian, installation, apt, dependencies, libraries

I'm trying to use mozjpeg as a drop-in replacement library for jpeg-turbo. I'm perfectly able to fetch the sources and compile them as needed and even create a deb-file from it which I can use to install the package (e.g. `apt-get install ./mozjpeg_3.2_amd64.deb`).

To be clear, note that these two packages are supposed to provide the exact same interface and hence be functionally equivalent. Accordingly, a dependency on jpeg-turbo should be satisfied by mozjpeg.

Ok, going on, when I then continue to install dependant packages (e.g. ghostscript development headers, `libgs-dev`), I run into errors as these have declared a dependency on `libjpeg62-turbo-dev`:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-HuzNRO/0-libjpeg62-turbo-dev_1%3a1.5.1-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/jerror.h', which is also in package mozjpeg 3.2-20170219
```

Now, that a conflict arises at this point is of course logical. Is there a way to prevent this? Can I tell the dependency system that mozjpeg satisfies the dependency on jpeg-turbo so that any packages which depend on jpeg-turbo will install using the replacement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependencies are encoded by the package maintainers in the packages themselves as a dependency on a specific package name and/or version. There is, as far as I know, no method that you as an end-user can manipulate such dependencies from for instance  an apt-get config file .

It is possible create dependency relations on specific functionality, rather than depending on a specific package name, via a [`virtual-package`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual_pkg) when multiple packages are offering identical functionality, but typically that requires coordination with the other package maintainers.

For your own environment you could try that without any such coordination though:

There are a number of warnings in the manual, but when you build the package for mozjpeg you can use the [`Provides: jpeg-turbo`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-virtual) option to make it a virtual package that, once it is installed, would satisfy dependency requirements for packages that need jpeg-turbo.

Comment: Already linked from the side menu but quite relevant http://serverfault.com/q/250224/37681